# Laravel 5.4MassAssignmentException in Model.php line 225: _token

Tags: php, laravel

I was making a system wherein only administrator can adding users.
I have a problem, becouse after filling  the form  I receives error who looks like : 
MassAssignmentException in Model.php line 225:
_token

My Form:

```
               {!! Form::open(['url'=>'adminpanel/adduser/store','class'=>'form-horizontal']) !!}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-4 control-label">
                        {!! Form::label('nameandsurname','imie i nazwisko:') !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        {!! Form::text('nameandsurname', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-4 control-label">
                        {!! Form::label('PESEL','PESEL:') !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        {!! Form::text('PESEL',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-4 control-label">
                        {!! Form::label('adress','adres:') !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        {!! Form::text('adress',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-4 control-label">
                        {!! Form::label('position','stanowisko:') !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        {!! Form::text('position',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-4 control-label">
                        {!! Form::label('email','email:') !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        {!! Form::text('email',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-4 control-label">
                        {!! Form::label('leavesdays','liczbadniwolnych:') !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        {!! Form::text('leavesdays',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>


                {!! Form::hidden('password', null) !!}
                {!! Form::hidden('remember_token',null) !!}
```

This is User Model :

```
            use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */


protected $fillable = [
    'nameandsurname', 'email','PESEL','adress','position','leavesdays',

];
protected $table = 'users';
/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
```

Request in controller :

```
           public function store(AddUserRequest $request)
           {
          //        User::create($request->except('_token'));
    $newUser = User::create($request->all());
    $newUser->save();

    return redirect('/adminpanel/admindashboard');
}
```

Migration:

```
      public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nameandsurname',40);
        $table->string('PESEL',9);
        $table->string('adress',30);
        $table->enum('position',array('employer','worker','accountant'));
        $table->string('email',100)->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->integer('leavesdays');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I was looking for this problem on the internet, but any suggestion helped me.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Laravel's mass assignment feature you have to provide an array on the `create()` method like

```
User::create(['nameandsurname'=>'some_value', 'email'=>'sampleEmail@mil.com']...etc);
```

Have in mind that if you provide fields that are not defined in the `$fillable` you will also get an exception. Take a look on doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment for more information

Answer (score 0):

`$fillable` tells Elequent the expected parameters for the model constructor.So, best practice is to create your `User` as

```
$request_data = $request->only(['nameandsurname', 'email','PESEL','adress','position','leavesdays']);

$user = User::create($request_data);
```

Comment: I do this, but i get : MassAssignmentException in Model.php line 225:
nameandsurname

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of `User::create($request->all());` you can do something like this :

```
User::create($request->only((new User())->getFillable()));
```

With getFillable you will get all your fields that are in the `protected $fillable` variable and the `$request->only($fields)` will only provide those fields

Comment: I try it, but before this change I get : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'nameandsurname' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2017-04-18 17:45:14, 2017-04-18 17:45:14))

Comment: when you do `dd($request->only((new User())->getFillable()))` what does it give you ?

Comment: when i use : dd($request->only((new User())->getFillable())) it give me [], but when I use : dd($request) it give me : **array:9 [▼
"_token" => "bWf3WcdXGY2uDqx5z9vBVO5Fg3MuBHG2BPXQFth4"
"nameandsurname" => "sdadsa"
"PESEL" => "dsadas"
"adress" => "dsadsa"
"position" => "saddsadsa"
"email" => "sdadsa"
"leavesdays" => "adsdsadsadsa"
"password" => null
"remember_token" => null
]

Comment: Weird, maybe try
`User::create(['nameandsurname' => $request->nameandsurname, 'email' => $request->email,'PESEL' => $request->PESEL,'adress' => $request->adress,'position' => $request->position,'leavesdays' => $request->leavesdays]);`

Comment: I get this : MassAssignmentException in Model.php line 225:
nameandsurname

Comment: Not a real fix (i.e. be careful with that) if inside your model you put `protected $guarded = []` ?